# Combine post values and remove empty

Tags: php, arrays, post

I have two sets of arrays coming from `$_POST`. Keys for both will be numeric and the count will be the same, since they come in pairs as names and numbers:

```
$_POST[names]
(
    [0] => First
    [1] => Second
    [2] => 
    [3] => Fourth
)

$_POST[numbers]
(
    [0] => 10
    [1] => 
    [2] => 3
    [3] => 3
)
```

Now I need to combine those two, but remove each entry where either values are missing.

The result should be something like:

```
$finalArray
(
    [First] => 10
    [Fourth] => 3
)
```

Post data is dynamically created so there might be different values missing based on user input.

I tried doing something like:

```
if (array_key_exists('names', $_POST)) {
        $names = array_filter($_POST['names']);
        $numbers = array_filter($_POST['numbers']);

        if($names and $numbers) {
           $final = array_combine($names, $numbers);

        }

    }
```

But I can't seem to filter it correctly, since its giving me an error:

> Warning: array_combine(): Both parameters should have an equal number of elements

Comment: can we assume that both arrays will always have the same count, and that keys will always be numeric?

Comment: Yes, both keys will be numeric and the count will be the same, since they come in pairs as names and numbers.

Comment: @Alko I have added some relevant comments to each answer.  Please look review the page for some insights that may be educational to you and others.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

How about using `array_filter` with `ARRAY_FILTER_USE_BOTH` flag on?

```
<?php
    $array1 = [
        0 => "First",
        1 => "Second",
        2 => "",
        3 => "Fourth",
    ];

    $array2 = [
        0 => 10,
        1 => "",
        2 => 3,
        3 => 3,
    ];

    var_dump(array_filter(array_combine($array1, $array2), function($value, $key) {
        return $key == "" || $value == "" ? false : $value;
    }, ARRAY_FILTER_USE_BOTH ));

/*
Output:

array(2) {
  ["First"]=>
  int(10)
  ["Fourth"]=>
  int(3)
}
*/
```

Comment: This is not trustworthy because `array_filter()` will kill `0` keyed/valued elements.  http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/3d5536ea2a35d83c12afd0c52ef2f3d03d7ec47d

Comment: I recommend this slight adjustment: `var_export(array_filter(array_combine($array1, $array2), function($value, $key) {
    return $key!=="" && $value!=="";
}, ARRAY_FILTER_USE_BOTH));`

Answer (score 3):

Here's a fun way:

```
$result = array_flip(array_flip(array_filter(array_combine($_POST['names'],
                                                           $_POST['numbers']))));
```

Comment: This is not trustworthy because `array_filter()` will kill `0` valued elements.

Comment: Double flipping will also damage the output when there are duplicate numbers in `$_POST['numbers']`.  http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/6fc1774f9ea5f804760ab0184c02a49b641e3aa8  Please improve/rewrite this answer, too much wrong with it right now.

Answer (score 2):

```
// create array using $_POST['names'] as keys and $_POST['numbers'] as values
$result = array_combine($_POST['names'], $_POST['numbers']);
// remove entries that have empty values
$result = array_filter($result);
// remove entry with empty key
unset($result[null]);

print_r($result);
```

Comment: This is not trustworthy because `array_filter()` will kill `0` valued elements.

Answer (score 1):

If both arrays will have the same count, and the keys will always be numeric, you could do the following:

```
$total = count($_POST['names']);
$final = array();
for ($i = 0; $i < $total; $i++) {
    if (trim($_POST['names'][$i]) != '' && trim($_POST['numbers'][$i]) != '') {
        $final[$_POST['names'][$i]] = $_POST['numbers'][$i];
    }
}
```

Or if you prefer to use a `foreach` instead of `for`

```
$final = array();
foreach ($_POST['names'] as $key => $value) {
    if (trim($value) != '' && trim($_POST['numbers'][$key]) != '') {
        $final[$value] = $_POST['numbers'][$key];
    }
}
```

Comment: This answer is `0` key & value "safe" and duplicate `numbers` "safe".  I would call this answer very clean if those `trim()` calls weren't in there.  For the scope of this question, the `trim()` calls are not necessary.  Good answer.  Demo: http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/f0f517f82460b9efd27325bbd247ca912083dcbf

Answer (score 0):

Takeing your previous information into account:

> both keys will be numeric and the count will be the same, since they come in pairs as names and numbers

```
$myNewArray = array();

$count = 0;
foreach ($_POST['names'] as $bufferArray)
{
  if (($bufferArray[$count]!=NULL)&&($_POST['numbers][$count]!=NULL))
  {
    array_push($myNewArray, array($bufferArray[$count] => $_POST['numbers][$count]);
  }
  $count++;
}
```

Let me know if that helps! :)

---

**Note:** I made some edits to the code.

Also, my previous code checks if the empty array spaces are NULL. If you want to check if they are either NULL or "" (empty), then replace the line of code with:

```
if (($bufferArray[$count]!=NULL)&&($_POST['numbers][$count]!=NULL)&&($bufferArray[$count]!="")&&($_POST['numbers][$count]!=""))
{...}
```

Comment: This method has multiple syntax errors.  After fixing them, it still mangles the output and doesn't get close to returning the correct result.  Downvoted.  Always test your code before posting so that you don't confuse future readers, waste their time, or trick unsuspecting researchers to use bad code.  Working demo of bad output: http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/128d6609efaa691a8ca02499316ff39370ec9028